# Read the screen backlight value from officially Raspberry Pi 7" Display

Tags: c#, raspberry-pi, windows-10-iot-core

I am trying to get the actual screen backlight value from the official Raspberry 7" Touch LCD. I know that the "set" command is 0x86 but what is the "get" command? A guess would be 0x85 or 0x87.

Here is a Code example which I am trying to get to work:

```
public async Task<bool> IsDimmed()
    {
        string i2cDeviceSelector = I2cDevice.GetDeviceSelector();
        I2cConnectionSettings i2CConnectionSettings = new I2cConnectionSettings(0x45);
        IReadOnlyList<DeviceInformation> deviceInformationCollection = await DeviceInformation.FindAllAsync(i2cDeviceSelector);
        if (deviceInformationCollection.Count > 0)
        {
            var i2CDevice = await I2cDevice.FromIdAsync(deviceInformationCollection[0].Id, i2CConnectionSettings);
            var readBuffer = new byte[1];
            var command = new byte[] { 0x85 };
            try
            {
                i2CDevice.WriteRead(command, readBuffer);
                i2CDevice.Dispose();
                if (readBuffer[0] < 0xff) return true;
            }
            catch {  }
        }
        return false;
    }
```

I expect the "readBuffer" to have the actual brightness value from 0x00 to 0xff.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tried to find the command to get the touch screen backlight value,but did not find any helpful info about this. There is a [topic](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/cb970022-01cc-4cac-9b2a-2a322ecdb372/raspberry-pi-7quot-display-control?forum=WindowsIoT) on MSDN forum, i think you can get some helpful information from IoTGirl mentioned.

> There is not a traditional Windows display driver for RPix. All
>   display rendering is done by VC4 firmware (GPU microcode managed by Pi
>   Foundation).
>
> Further to Andre's response, the I2c channel between LCD panel and VC4
>   is not exposed to Windows, because VC4 takes full ownership of that
>   I2c channel.
>
> Even if it could be accomplished, sharing the same i2c between Windows
>   and VC4 will be problematic. It for sure will break touch
>   functionality.